# How to call multi query in php using SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, html-table

Below is the code:

```
 <div class="device_data">
        <div class="device_data_container">    
                <table>
                      <th> Sr No. </th>
                      <th> Device Name </th>
                      <th> Sensor Mac ID </th>
                      <th> Minimum </th>
                      <th> Maximum </th>
                      <th> Ambient </th>
                      <th> Average </th>
                      <th> Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Time </th>
                    </tr>
                        <?php   
                        $sql = "SELECT device_id,device_name,sensor_mac_id,t_min,t_max,t_amb,t_avg,date FROM device_data WHERE device_name='Sky' ";
                        $result =mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                        //$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);                 
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
                            // output data of each row
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['device_id'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['device_name'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['sensor_mac_id'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['t_min'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['t_max'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['t_amb'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['t_avg'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }echo '</table>';
                        }else{      
                                echo '0 result';
                        }
                        mysqli_close($conn);
                    ?>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
        <table>
                      <th> Sr No. </th>
                      <th> Device Name </th>
                      <th> Sensor Mac ID </th>
                      <th> Minimum </th>
                      <th> Maximum </th>
                      <th> Ambient </th>
                      <th> Average </th>
                      <th> Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Time </th>
                    </tr>
                        <?php   
                        $sql = "SELECT device_id,device_name,sensor_mac_id,t_min,t_max,t_amb,t_avg,date FROM device_data WHERE device_name='Rocky' ";
                        $result =mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                        //$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);                 
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
                            // output data of each row
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                            {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['device_id'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['device_name'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['sensor_mac_id'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['t_min'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['t_max'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['t_amb'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['t_avg'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }echo '</table>';
                        }else{      
                                echo '0 result';
                        }
                        mysqli_close($conn);
                    ?>
          </table>
    </div>
```

Error:

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\details.php on line 212
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\details.php on line 214 0 result
>   Warning: mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\details.php on line 232

I am able to get data from first device with name Sky but not with Rocky

Comment: Consider fetching results for both devices in a single query

Answer (score 1):

You have closed the connection after the fist loop

mysqli_close($conn);

Please remove it and close the connection somewhere else in your project properly.

BTW, it is always a good idea to crate a global connection in your project.